# Составление дерева

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Как можно составить дерево, имея следующие данные:

Например, у меня есть названия компьютеров (`y101-ws01`, `y102-ws01`, `y101-ws02`, `y103-ws01`). Мне нужно сделать дерево, где главным каталогом будет `у101`, а там уже `y101-ws01` и `y101-ws01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать класс `Map` для решения Вашей задачи, вот пример:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"y101-ws01", "y102-ws01", "y101-ws02", "y103-ws01"};

        Map<String, Set<String>> tree = new HashMap<>();
        for (String fullComputerName : names) {
            String rootName = fullComputerName.split("-")[0];
            tree.computeIfAbsent(rootName, key -> new HashSet<>())
                    .add(fullComputerName);
        }

        tree.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, для каждой группы (которая идёт до знака `'-'`) мы имеем `Set` из компьютеров, которые в ней находятся. Метод `computeIfAbsent()` создаст новый сет для ключа (коим является имя группы) только в первый раз, затем вернёт нам либо ранее существовавший `Set`, либо только что созданный.

Comment: А как потом можно сделать так, чтобы эти данные отображались в jTree, в той же иерархии?

Comment: @AsmaRod Не хотелось бы копипастить, поэтому держите [официальный туториал от `Oracle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: и еще один вопрос. Вот мы получили y101=[y101-ws01, y101-ws02], y102=[y102-ws01]. Как мне в то дерево занести просто y101. Если я заношу rootName, то у101 получается два раза.

Comment: Все я разобрался, 
`for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> m : tree.entrySet()) {
                   String rootName = m.getKey();
                   System.out.println(rootName);
            }`

Comment: @AsmaRod Если я Вам помог, Вы можете повысить рейтинг моего ответа и/или отметить его как лучший ответ. Буду признателен. Если я могу Вам ещё чем-то помочь, спрашивайте, помогу.